# MySQL order by two columns in or-clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I have a table in MySQL with some data like below:

```
id name      first_name
===============================
1  hello     
2            many
3            alive
4  persons
```

How can I make the result look like this

```
id name      first_name
===============================
3            alive
1  hello     
2            many
4  persons
```

So, the sorting should be alphabetic on name and/or first_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the order by should look like

```
order by coalesce(name,first_name)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the values are empty strings rather than null. @randyh22 solution works for either null or empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

The following query would do the work.

```
SELECT *
FROM nameTable
ORDER BY IFNULL(name,first_name)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM nameTable
ORDER BY coalesce(name,first_name)
```

**N:B:** If you cannot access [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e95504/2/0).

```
CREATE TABLE `nameTable` (
`ID`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name`  varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`first_name`  varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO `nametable` VALUES ('1', 'hello', null);
INSERT INTO `nametable` VALUES ('2', null, 'many');
INSERT INTO `nametable` VALUES ('3', null, 'alive');
INSERT INTO `nametable` VALUES ('4', 'persons', null);
```

**Note:**

The main difference between the two is that `IFNULL` function takes two arguments and returns the first one if it's not `NULL` or the second if the first one is `NULL`.

`COALESCE` function can take two or more parameters and returns the first non-`NULL` parameter, or NULL if all parameters are `null`.

Comment: These solutions don't work if the values are empty strings rather than null. @randyh22 solution works for either null or empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sortby column which is a concatenation of the two other columns.

```
SELECT id, `name`, first_name, CONCAT(IFNULL(`name`,''),IFNULL(first_name,'')) AS sortby
FROM
table1
ORDER BY sortby
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY CONCAT(name,first_name) ASC
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the values are null rather than empty strings. @randyh22 solution works for either null or empty strings.